# Finding records with similar and distinct fields

Tags: c#, linq

From a list of objects that contain the following information (id, name, address, code):

```
1,Andrea,15th St,123
2,Sarah,15th St,124
3,Andrea,15th St,134
4,Andrea,16th St,124
```

I want to retrieve the lines that have the same name and address but different code. In this example:

```
1,Andrea,15th St,123
3,Andrea,15th St,134
```

I've gone about it with Linq, learning about it for the first time. I was able to find the duplicates:

```
var sameEmail =
        from l in list
        group l by new { l.name, l.address} into na
        where na.Count() > 1
        select na.Key;
```

But I can't find a way to make sure I only get the records with different codes. With that, I would also get the last line, but since it has the same code, I don't want it. Is there a way to do this with Linq? Or any other way in C#?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `Distinct` in order to get distinct values

```
var sameEmail =
    from l in list
    group l by new { l.name, l.address} into na
    where na.Select(a => a.code).Distinct().Count() > 1
    select na.Key;
```

Comment: Ugh. So obvious now. Thanks a lot!